Sort date by ascending order and print lines from the location dates
I have one txt file with many dates like 2018 2019 2023.
I want to sort them by ascending order and print the lines where the dates has been found.To find the dates on the file i use this code.
file='wine.txt' #name of the file
if(os.path.isfile(file)): #cheak if file exists or not
    with open(file,'r') as i:
        for j in i: #we will travarse line by line in file
            try:
                match=re.search(r'\d{4}',j) #regular expression for date
                print(match.group()) #print date if match is found
            except AttributeError:
                pass
else:
    print("file does not exist")

Now i want to sort date by ascending order and print the lines where they have been found.Expected output
Found 2018 : the pomerol wine is better in 2018 but... blablabla
Found 2020 : the french wine production is not very efficient in 2020 due to weather condition...

How can i use sort working with txt file ?

You can store the dates (as integers) and the lines containing the dates in a list of tuples and sort the tuples.
import os
import re

file = 'wine.txt'

if os.path.isfile(file):
    lines_with_dates = []  # A list to store tuples of (date, line) format

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            match = re.search(r'\b\d{4}\b', line)  # Regular expression for date
            if match:
                lines_with_dates.append((int(match.group()), line.strip()))  # Store date and line

    # Sort lines by date
    lines_with_dates.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Print sorted lines with dates
    for date, line in lines_with_dates:
        print(f"Found {date} : {line}")
else:
    print("File does not exist")

